# android fragment - data passing - best practice

Tags: android, android-fragments

When passing data to a fragment why do this -  (i.e. the way you are supposed to do it)

```
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;



public static ReviewPagesFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ReviewPagesFragment fragment = new ReviewPagesFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}
```

instead of doing this

```
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;



public static ReviewPagesFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    ReviewPagesFragment fragment = new ReviewPagesFragment();
    fragment.mParam1 = param1;
    fragment.mParam2 = param2;
    return fragment;
}
```

the second way is simpler and gives you better performance. I am a fan of K.I.S.S. So my question is - why is the first way the recommended way and what benefit come from doing it that way?

Comment: Some time ago I asked very similar question ;) - If you would like to see it was explained there see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10316527/dailogfragment-getarguments-setarguments-why-passing-arguments-in-a-bundle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using a Bundle allows your fragment to persist state if it's recreated.  Here's a more thorough explaination:  [Best practice for instantiating a new Android Fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)